# My odoo recordset , how to do can group by dict key..to new dict?

Tags: python, odoo

my python list data is this:

```
[{'partner': res.partner(985,), 'account_id': account.account(193,), 'price_total': 420.0}, {'partner': res.partner(985,), 'account_id': account.account(194,), 'price_total': 260.0}, {'partner': res.partner(985,), 'account_id': account.account(95,), 'price_total': 600.0}]
```

want to result:

```
dict_list = [{'partner_id': res.partner(985,),'data': [{'account_id': account.account(193,), 'price_total': 420}, {'account_id': account.account(194,), 'price_total': 260}, {'account_id': account.account(95,), 'price_total': 600.0}]}]
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'res' is not defined`

Comment: I believe `res` is a class object (as well as `account`) that have `partner` and `account` methods, respectively. Would work if you generalize the data and remove `res` and `account` to just an int value.

Comment: YES. account and partner is odoo model ..class object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the initial list data, saving the value of `partner` and deleting it from the dictionary so that you only have `{'account_id':193, 'price_total':420.0}`. Now go through the output resulting list and see if the `partner_id` already exists. If so, append the dictionary quoted above. If not, put a new dictionary into the output list with the corresponding partner id and data.

Input (modified since I don't have access to your `res` and `account` classes):

```
dataset = [{'partner': 985, 
      'account_id': 193, 
      'price_total': 420.0},
    {'partner': 985, 
     'account_id': 194, 
     'price_total': 260.0}, 
     {'partner': 985, 
      'account_id': 95, 
      'price_total': 600.0}]
```

Code (sorry I used `res` in my code as short for result, it will conflict with your class name):

```
result = []

for data in dataset:
    partner_id = data['partner']
    del data['partner']
    if partner_id in [res['partner_id'] for res in result]:
        for res in result:
            if res['partner_id'] == partner_id:

                res['data'].append(data)
    else:
        result.append({'partner_id':partner_id, 'data':[data]})
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'partner_id': 985, 'data': [{'account_id': 193, 'price_total': 420.0}, {'account_id': 194, 'price_total': 260.0}, {'account_id': 95, 'price_total': 600.0}]}]
```

Comment: thank you ..i got it..record this ..to notepad.